# Bluetooth problem on Lubuntu 12.04.2 LTS?

Tags: lubuntu, bluetooth

I'm new to Linux and am having terrible difficulty getting my bluetooth devices to pair/connect. I'm using a bluetooth dongle on my Dell Inspiron 910 running Lubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. I've tried blueman bluetooth manager and bluetooth-applet (which I think came preinstalled with Ubuntu) but both crash my system whenever I attempt to pair/connect devices.

I don't fully understand it at this point but I've read that there is a problem with the bluez package/stack. There doesn't seem to be much support availbable the subject. At this point I'm completely unsure as to what package I should be using for bluetooth functionality or what packages I need to have installed/uninstalled. If you could point me in the right direction I'd be very greatful. I recently bought a Logitech K810 keyboard which I can only stare at for the moment.

Comment: VTC because there is no information about BT hardware and the question is too old.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with this nice piece of hardware. Pairing fails after entering the PIN. The keyboard reacts on the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. The message: pairing fails - with the following entries in the sys log:

```
Apr 30 13:19:16 wetab bluetoothd[889]: Discovery session 0xb9639b68 with :1.48 activated
Apr 30 13:19:32 wetab bluetoothd[889]: Stopping discovery
Apr 30 13:19:33 wetab bluetoothd[889]: Unknown Management opcode 23 (index 0)
Apr 30 13:19:43 bluetoothd[889]: last message repeated 6 times
Apr 30 13:19:43 wetab bluetoothd[889]: hci0: Cancel Pair Device (0x001a) failed: Invalid Parameters (0x0d)
```

I managed to use the keyboard anyway - with some drawbacks.

Just: `hidd --search` and one need to install:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez-compat
```

OK, every restart I have to press the pairing button and start the command again. I do not trust the encryption either. But at least I can work.

I use a fresh Raring Ringtail installation which works just fine with my very cheap rubber bluetooth keyboard...

Hope it gets better later as it seems to be an implementation flaw in Linux as the K810 works fine with my Android.